# Wanhao Duplicator i3 Mini - Not reaching temperature -> screen freezes

Tags: hotend, wanhao, duplicator-i3-mini

I have been having some issues with my Cocoon Create Model Maker/Wanhao Duplicator i3 Mini. The hotend doesn't get up to temperature.

I will go to any of the heating functions (start print, preheat, add filament, etc.) and it will begin to reheat the nozzle. The temperature rises until eventually, it stops at any number that is not the desired print temp and the screen freezes. Sometimes it will stop at 150 °C sometimes 180 °C. It all seems quite random but the screen is frozen when this happens.

If anyone had any thoughts it would be much appreciated. My last printer was abandoned due to a similar issue and it's incredibly frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was posted in a comment, as the asker hasn't posted an answer yet, it is answered in this community wiki answer:

> Ended up replacing the thermistor which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the thermistor is not fully seated and does not measure temperature effectively.

Try inserting the thermistor into the hole by filling the gaps with metal wire or conductive paste.